# quiero poner una lista al lado de la otra y que queden alineadas

Tags: html, css, display

puse cada ul al lado de la otra con un display inline-bloc pero la ultima lista que tiene la class choose-general queda mas abajo que las demás, no a la misma altura, como puedo hacer que si lo haga? ya intente llamando desde la class y añadiéndole un margen-top de -20% pero se agrande el background, no sube la lista

```
     <div class="choose">
      <ul>
        <li><h5>Americas</h5></li>
        <li>Argentina</li>
        <li>Canada</li>
        <li>Mexico</li>
        <li>Brasil</li>
        <li>United States</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><h5>Europe</h5></li>
        <li>United Kingdom</li>
        <li>France</li>
        <li>España</li>
        <li>Belgium</li>
        <li>Italy</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><h5>Asia/Pacific</h5></li>
        <li>India</li>
        <li>Australia</li>
        <li>Malasya</li>
        <li>Singapore</li>
        <li>China</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="choose-general">
        <li><h5>All Other Locations</h5></li>
        <li>International</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

     css/SASS
     
    .choose{
      background-color: $color-general;
      ul{
       list-style: none;
       display:inline-block;
       font-size: small;
        li{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ocupar [css grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) con lo cual se hace más fácil alinear en vertical

```css
.choose{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: small;

  }
li{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="choose">
      <ul>
        <li><h5>Americas</h5></li>
        <li>Argentina</li>
        <li>Canada</li>
        <li>Mexico</li>
        <li>Brasil</li>
        <li>United States</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><h5>Europe</h5></li>
        <li>United Kingdom</li>
        <li>France</li>
        <li>España</li>
        <li>Belgium</li>
        <li>Italy</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><h5>Asia/Pacific</h5></li>
        <li>India</li>
        <li>Australia</li>
        <li>Malasya</li>
        <li>Singapore</li>
        <li>China</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="choose-general">
        <li><h5>All Other Locations</h5></li>
        <li>International</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```